# How to find HTTP GETs in Wireshark

Tags: networking, http, wireshark

How can I use the filter in Wireshark to find only those lines that have HTTP GET in them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put this string in the `Filter:` field:

```
http.request.method == "GET"
```

and click on `Apply`.

You might find it useful to click on `Filter:` to see a list of pre-defined filters and to click on `Expression...` to see a list of terms that you can use to build your own filter expressions. For example, scroll down the `Expression...` list to `HTTP - Hypertext Transfer Protocol` and click on the `+` to see a list of HTTP-related terms. Valid relations appear in the center of the dialog box and values can be entered on the right. Clicking on some of the pre-defined filters under `Filter:` will show you how the filters were constructed and give you an idea of how to construct your own.